# Why are keywords like "final" and "mut" necessary?

Tags: java, rust

https://www.baeldung.com/java-final-performance
This blog gives an example of using the `final` keyword in java to improve performance. Here is the example they give:

```
public static String concatNonFinalStrings() {
    String x = "x";
    String y = "y";
    return x + y;
}

public static String concatFinalStrings() {
    final String x = "x";
    final String y = "y";
    return x + y;
}
```

Apparently, the compiler will optimize `concatFinalStrings()` to just return `"xy"`. Why can't the compiler do the same for `concatNonFinalStrings()`? `x` and `y` are limited in scope and they are never used anywhere else. Surely, then, the compiler should be able to treat those as if they were final? It's not like there can be some outside entity that may change the value of `x` and `y`, because they are inaccessible outside the function. The blog I've linked calls these "effectively final" and states that the compiler won't perform code optimizations on "effectively final" variables. Why not?

Furthermore, why do keywords like `mut` in Rust exist? Maybe it makes sense in Java where you can have public variables and you don't know what other `.class` files exist, but in Rust, if the whole thing is compiling at once, surely the compiler could just deduce which variables are `mut` by seeing which variables change their value? Do these now only exist for the sake of making the code more clear and not actually provide any sort of optimization?

Comment: Well, _you_ can tell they have limited scope and it won't change but the compiler cannot automatically tell.  The `final` keyword is basically _our_ way of telling the compiler that those variables will not change and can be optimized.

Comment: I know nothing about Java, nor am I any kind of expert on Rust, but as someone with a passing acquaintance and interest in that language - it seems blindingly obvious that the `mut` keyword is nothing to do with compiler optimisations, but everything to do with making the code's intent clear to other developers who read it, as well as catching potential mistakes. Making everything immutable by default and forcing developers to explicitly mark those variables whose values can change, both catches accidental mutations and conveys clear intent to a reader.

Comment: Don’t ask two entirely unrelated questions at once. Which one are we supposed to answer, the one about Java or the one about Rust? Besides that, everything coming form baeldung.com should be taken with a grain of salt. What you see here, is a tiny corner case of `final` variables, *compile-time constants*. How often, do you think, will you concatenate local variables actually being *compile-time constants* in real life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the Rust question, you can think of mutable/immutable declaration as a way of:

1. Express your intent in code
2. Ask the compiler to ensure your intent is maintained

E.g:
If the correctness of your program is depends on a variable x never changed after assigned to result of foo(), you can declare: `let x = foo()`. From now on, you can put your mind at ease knowing that x will not be accidentally assigned to other values.

On the other hand, if Rust does not have keyword `mut`, the compiler can still deduce mutability of a variable for sure. However, if you have a code like so:

```
let x = foo();
...
x = 42;
```

The compiler can not know if the assignment `x = 42` is by mistake or it's your intent. In other words, we - the programmers lose a powerful check.

So, I think the requirement to declare mutability of variables is more about us than about the compiler itself. And, as I see, it's quite a common theme in the Rust language, a lot of requirements is in place to help us catch our mistakes early and often.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, even though the compiler *could* deduce a lot of things by being "smart enough", you have to take into account that compilation time is bounded. The compiler can't just try all the optimizations known to mankind to see if any fits, because that would be too long. Since the static optimization can be enforced by the `final` keyword, there isn't much point in the compiler doing that optimization for you (which would take time).

---

As for Rust, it's a similar answer (trying to figure out the minimum amount of variables that should be mutable for the code to run would be very long), with the addition that even if it was the case, the behavior would be very hard to predict, because a single change could completely modify the minimum set of variables that should be mutable for the code to be sound (if that even exists), and if that doesn't exist, the error reported would be horrible (because the compiler can't incriminate any particular piece of code, it's just that overall the code can't be made sound). To see some examples of this behavior, you could look at polymorphic variants in OCaml, where the compiler will infer the most general type for every value, but if it's not possible, error messages can quickly become horrendous.

A final argument as for explicit mutability in Rust is interfaces: sure, the compiler knows everything when compiling, but when I write a library and declare an interface (any interface, may it be a function signature or anything else), I may want to enforce mutability of a variable or, in the contrary, enforce its immutability, even without knowing how the consumer will use it. This allows the compiler to typecheck my library, including for mutability, even without knowing how it will actually be used.

---

And I didn't even mention *readability*: being explicit often also means being more readable.

*Side Note: what you describe in Java is referred to as [effectively final](http://ilkinulas.github.io/programming/java/2016/03/27/effectively-final-java.html).*

Comment: I'm not convinced that it would take too long to compile; is there any source for this?
Rust will fail to compile if you try to mutate an immutable variable, and will show you the variable that needs "mut" added to it, so it clearly already checks it at compile time.

Comment: @tryna_learn I don't have anything right away, if I find some I will post it; but I didn't just invent that out of my hat: I saw a similar question asked on the Rust forums about why the compiler is not able to understand that if statements with boolean literals only execute one branch, and the answer was something like "checking all these corner cases would take too much time, our compiler is slow enough without these".

Comment: @tryna_learn as for the Rust part, it's not that easy (I really encourage you to google OCaml's polymorphic variants to see an example). Suppose I mutate a variable that the compiler has, so far, deduced should be immutable. Where is the bug? Is it that I mutate the variable, or does it lie it what made the compiler deduce it should be immutable? There is no way to know, therefore the compiler has to report both possible sources.

Comment: Besides this, you have to understand that Rust already runs something similar to what you described for lifetimes, called the "borrow checker". Now, the mutability of variable depends on the lifetimes, but reciprocally the borrow checker knows mutable and immutable borrows (pointers) have different semantics, and thus works differently if it's mutable or not.